# Balanced based representation

Tags: numeral-representations

I'm interested in balanced base $B$ representation for fixed point arithmetic. The paper *Fixed-point arithmetic in SHE schemes* (Costache, Smart, Vivek and Waller, in *Proceedings of 23rd International Conference on Selected Areas in Cryptography (SAC 2016)*, Springer *Lecture Notes in Computer Science*, vol. 10532, pp. 401–422, 2016; [PDF](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/250.pdf)) provides two examples using balanced based $B=3$. However, I don't understand the 2nd second representation, i.e. 
$$\frac{8}{3}=10.\bar{1} $$
where $\bar{1}=-1$. 
More generally speaking, I'm also interested in balanced form representation $B=5, 7$.
I believe this should be a well-known problem, though I was not able to google it. Do you know some relevant literature to this?

Comment: This seems like a pure math question, and so belongs to [math.se].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{8}{3}=3 - \frac13=1\cdot3^1 + 0\cdot3^0 +(-1)\cdot3^{-1}=(10.\bar{1})_3$$

Since $\frac83$ is not equal to $\dfrac p{5^i}$ for any integer $p$ and $i$, it cannot be expressed as a fixed-point balanced base-5 number. Instead, infinite periodical fraction part has to be used, where $\bar2=-2$.

$$\frac{8}{3}=5-2+\frac{-2}5+\frac2{25}+\frac{-2}{125}+\frac2{625}+\frac{-2}{3125}+\frac2{15625}+\cdots=(1\bar2.\bar{2}2\bar{2}2\bar{2}2\cdots)_5$$

Let us see it step by step.
$\frac{8}{3}\approx5$
$\frac{8}{3}-5=\frac{-7}3\approx -2$
$\frac{8}{3}-(5-2)=\frac{-1}3\approx \frac {-2}5$
$\frac{8}{3}-(5-2+\frac{-2}5)=\frac15\frac{1}3\approx \frac15\frac {2}5$
$\frac{8}{3}-(5-2+\frac{-2}5+\frac15\frac25)=\frac15\frac15\frac{-1}3\approx \frac15\frac15\frac {-2}5$
$\frac{8}{3}-(5-2+\frac{-2}5+\frac15\frac25+\frac15\frac15\frac{-2}5)=\frac15\frac15\frac15\frac{1}3\approx \frac15\frac15\frac15\frac {2}5$
$\frac{8}{3}-(5-2+\frac{-2}5+\frac15\frac25+\frac15\frac15\frac{-2}5+\frac15\frac15\frac15\frac25)=\frac15\frac15\frac15\frac15\frac{-1}3\approx \frac15\frac15\frac15\frac15\frac {-2}5$
$\vdots$

You can work out the the balanced base-7 number with periodical fraction for $\dfrac 83$.

For the case of base 3, you can take a look at [balanced ternary at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balanced_ternary).

Comment: The section "3.1 Balanced Base-B Encoding" of [that paper you mentioned](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/250.pdf) can be considered as a nice introduction.

Comment: There are 13 references near the end of that paper. You could read and trace some of them.

Answer (score 2):

The expression $10.\overline{1}$ should be interpreted as follows:
$$
1 \cdot 3^1 + 0 \cdot 3^0 + (-1) \cdot 3^{-1} = 3 - \frac{1}{3} = \frac{8}{3}.
$$
The interpretation of balanced base $b=2d+1$ is the same, with the digits ranging from $-d$ to $d$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. 
Do you know some relevant literature to this?
I would like to learn how to represent generic floating number such as 0.72?